# Able to plot on map but having trouble with st_contains

Tags: postgis

I am new to working with GIS, and am building a rails app that uses the [rgeo](https://github.com/rgeo/rgeo) gem and PostGIS.

I am trying to use geospatial data to determine the school district for a house. The house is represented by a point, and the school districts are represented by multipolygons. I have successfully plotted both on a map, and all appears to be working correctly, with the point falling inside of one of the polygons.

[image]

However, when I try to run the following code to determine which district the house is in, I get back an empty array:

```
>>  point = @property.coords
>> ES_Zone.where{ st_contains(geometry, point) }
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

I **think** that the SRIDs are the same on the points and polygons, because the factories for each show SRID 3785.

```
>> point.class
=> RGeo::Geos::CAPIPointImpl
>> point.factory
=> #<RGeo::Geos::CAPIFactory:0x860c5838 srid=3785 bufres=1 flags=8>

>> ES_Zone.first.geometry.class
=> RGeo::Geos::CAPIMultiPolygonImpl
>> ES_Zone.first.geometry.factory
=> #<RGeo::Geos::CAPIFactory:0x84889648 srid=3785 bufres=1 flags=8>
```

Any ideas on why this is happening, and suggestions for how to fix it?

Comment: you can post an answer to your own question - did you resolve this?

Comment: I'm exploring what @mtn.biker wrote, but so far no luck.

Comment: What does `ES_Zone.where{ st_contains(geometry, point) }.to_sql` return?

Answer (score 3):

Try the `&&` operator:

```
scope :containing, -> (point) { where("#{self.table_name}.geometry && ?", point) }
```

From http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.3/ch03.html:

> In general, you will want to use the "intersects operator" (&&) which
>   tests whether the bounding boxes of features intersect. The reason the
>   && operator is useful is because if a spatial index is available to
>   speed up the test, the && operator will make use of this. This can
>   make queries much much faster.
>
> You will also make use of spatial functions, such as Distance(),
>   ST_Intersects(), ST_Contains() and ST_Within(), among others, to
>   narrow down the results of your search. Most spatial queries include
>   both an indexed test and a spatial function test. The index test
>   serves to limit the number of return tuples to only tuples that might
>   meet the condition of interest. The spatial functions are then use to
>   test the condition exactly.

```
SELECT id, the_geom  FROM thetable
WHERE
the_geom && 'POLYGON((0 0, 0 10, 10 10, 10 0, 0 0))'
AND
ST_Contains(the_geom,'POLYGON((0 0, 0 10, 10 10, 10 0, 0 0))');
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this, tee. In your example, I assumed that area was a stand-in for the geometry column in my table, so I changed the scope to:   scope :containing, -> (point) { where("#{self.table_name}.geometry && ?", point) }
 However, it still returns an empty array as the result set.

Comment: I updated the example. You may want to try to get it working with raw SQL in psql.

Answer (score 2):

[ST_Contains()](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Contains.html) returns a boolean (true/false) whether one geometry falls within another.  Suggest you use [ST_Intersects()](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html) because it's faster and you don't have to be so careful with the order of the arguments. Note:

> There are certain subtleties to ST_Contains and ST_Within that are not intuitively obvious. For details check out Subtleties of OGC Covers, Contains, Within

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll use ST_Intersects in the future, but it does not seem to solve the underlying issue of getting back an empty array from my query.

Comment: Yes, I saw some of the comments - your issue doesn't seem to be the where clause of the query. I don't know rails & rgeo, but the next thing I'd look at is defining your point as a geometry. That is, I would think you need to do something like: ST_Intersects(geometry, (ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(point.X, point.Y),3785) )